# rails find(params[:id]) always returns id of the first element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to get the id of the user of the entry and return it in the documents show view

documents_controller.rb

```
def show
    @document = Document.find(params[:id])
    @entries = @document.entries  # to show all entries of a document
    @user = Entry.find(params[:id]).user_id # trying to get id of the user that was selected in the entry (always returns id of the first entry of a document)
end
```

documents/show.html.erb

```
<% @entries.each do |document| %>
    <tr>
        <% userName = @user%>
        <td><%= userName %></td> //always gets same id
        <% #end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Entry` has a `user_id` column, then just print it in the loop:

```
<% @entries.each do |document| %>
  <tr>
    <td>User id: <%= document.user_id %></td>

    <!-- if you're looking for the users name, I'd say you will be using: -->
    <td>User name: <%= User.find(document.user_id).name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

With `Entry.find(params[:id]).user_id` you were only finding that one `user_id` because you were find it by `params[:id]`, which was always the same in the loop.